# How can I access a C global variable/constant in Rust FFI?

Tags: c, rust, ffi

I need to access a value of a constant exported from C in Rust.

I want to read the value from the actual symbol, and not just copy'n'paste the value to Rust (in my case the value is a pointer, and C checks for pointer equality).

```
extern void *magic;
```

What's the syntax to get `magic: *const c_void` readable in Rust?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
use std::os::raw::c_void;

extern "C" {
    #[no_mangle]
    static magic: *const c_void;
}
```

Optionally, before the `extern` there can be `#[link(kind="static", name="<c library name>")]` to get the symbol actually linked.

Externally linkable items, even if constant, need be declared with `static`, not just `const` keyword (otherwise you get "extern items cannot be `const`").

Comment: `const` and `static` do not mean the same things in Rust and C. Rust's `static` defines that the value has an address, `const` does not. In this context, `const` is closer to a C `#define`. Review [the `const` vs `static` chapter in the first edition of the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/first-edition/const-and-static.html) to know more.

Comment: @Kornel how to do the same if the underlying C type is an int32 instead of a void?