# Why does a const disappear during linking when static doesn't?

Tags: c, memory-management, rust, linker

I have a function like this in my static library crate:

```
use super::*;

static BLANK_VEC: [u8; 16] = [0_u8; 16];
pub fn pad(name: &'static str) -> String {
    let mut res = String::from(name);
    res.push_str(&String::from_utf8_lossy(&BLANK_VEC[name.len()..]));
    res
}
```

When I link this to C code it works as expected, but if I link with the below code (the only difference being `const` instead of `static`) the label `BLANK_VEC` doesn't appear in the ELF file. It could compile and run until it gets a HardFault.

```
use super::*;

const BLANK_VEC: [u8; 16] = [0_u8; 16];
pub fn pad(name: &'static str) -> String {
    let mut res = String::from(name);
    res.push_str(&String::from_utf8_lossy(&BLANK_VEC[name.len()..]));
    res
}
```

Is this a bug on the Rust side? I think so because the `const` variable goes out of scope somehow. I can reference it and it compiles. Where is the ensured memory safety? Why didn't I have to use `unsafe` block to do that?

If this is something that depends on my linker: I use `arm-gcc-none-eabi`.

Edit: I understand why this happens but shouldn't Rust ensure that the user uses a variable that won't disappear?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/52753798/1021920 especially the text below "**Occurrences**"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52751597/what-is-the-difference-between-a-constant-and-a-static-variable-and-which-should/52753798#52753798 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45550387/how-can-i-access-a-c-global-variable-constant-in-rust-ffi escpecially the part `const and static do not mean the same things in Rust and C`

Comment: Since the question has already had a good answer posted, I think it would be better to leave this question as *why does the symbol `BLANK_VEC` not appear in the linker output* (which is what Masklinn answered) and open a new question for *why do I get an error when I run this code* (for which you should also provide more context, like the C code you're linking to). Changing the question after answers have already been posted is frowned on; opening a new question is fine and encouraged.

Comment: ok will do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a bug in rust: [`const`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.const.html) defines a constant *value* copied at every use-site (therefore not existing at runtime).

[`static`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.static.html) defines a global *variable* (which may or may not be constant), and is thus present in the final program, it's an actual single location in memory.

Comment: Ok but why does it compile. Isn't this unsafe. There should be at least a warning in my opinion about this. You are right this isn't a bug but this doesn't look like something Rust would do.

Comment: Linking is inherently unsafe; see [issue #28179](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/28179). However, I don't see any unsafety here. Why do you think this *particular* code is unsafe?

Comment: @selmanözlyn why would it not compile? There's nothing unsafe about anything, a `const` value just just copied at every use site. The linker is not under Rust's purview, that your C and linking are broken are not its problems.

Comment: Incidentally assuming that *private* statics are labelled in the output seems optimistic. I'd assume rustc within its right to not embed it since it's not visible in the output.

Comment: Linking is inherently unsafe might be my answer maybe. @Masklinn It would compile, I am saying why doesn't it force me to use a variable that won't disappear. When does it disappear when I am linking? When I use staticlib? Maybe there could be a warning right? So can we say there is no memory safety ensurance when linking.

Comment: @selmanözlyn Why do you think there is memory unsafety? Why would `BLANK_VEC` have to appear in the output for `pad` to be memory safe?

Comment: Because I am using it... And it lets me use it then I get a HardFault. The problem isn't the HardFault it is Rust letting me use it. I can use something doesn't appear and something that isn't in my scope

Comment: @selmanözlyn Anywhere Rust lets you use a name, it is by definition in scope. `BLANK_VEC` has no *linkage*, but that pertains to the use of the symbol `BLANK_VEC` and not the value behind it, which is always valid. It's like a `#define` in C, or an `inline constexpr` in C++, which also don't have linkage. I don't know what HardFault means, but if it's a runtime memory error, maybe that means you have an incorrect `unsafe` somewhere, or your C code is misbehaving. There's no reason Rust should warn you about using `BLANK_VEC` in this code; there's no way to use it to create unsafety.

Comment: Its a runtime memory error. How can I change the question? Clearly I wasn't understood.

Comment: @selmanözlyn you don't change questions days later, you create new questions, or go ask question on sites more adapted to discussing things (which SO *really* is not, because the commenting system is crap).

Comment: Ok thanks when I have the time I will open it.